# Possible to Call ArcPy Script From AddIn in ArcGIS 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, add-in

Is it possible to call an ArcPy script from a Java/.Net addin in ArcGIS 10.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there are several ways to do this. I would recommend building a script tool and packaging it with your add-in. I have a sample project that does this listed in this answer: [How can I programmatically get the path of "Python.exe" used by ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44411/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-path-of-python-exe-used-by-arcmap/44415#44415)

See also:

- [Running ArcPy script from ArcObjects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/28191/753)
- [Leveraging ArcPy in a .NET application](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000m0s000000)

Answer (score 2):

I call python script from my .net addin. I do it in a very simple way. I call it as I run process from .net code. Have a look at my code snippet

```
void RunPython(string scriptPath, string arguments)
{
     Process myProcess = new Process();
     try
     {
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = scriptPath + " " + arguments;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
            string result = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
 }
```

Comment: I do this myself to call a wxPython GUI from a .NET Add-In.